# jQuery hover over part of an image

Tags: jquery

I have an image and a span overlapping the image. When I mouse over the image, the span pops up, and on mouse out it retreats back down. 

 **Here is a simplified demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cCYHp/**

 The problem:

 I would like the spans to only popup when the SPAN area is moused over, not the image. I tried to do a `.hide()` effect but it did not work (it is commented out in the demo). I think this is because once the span is hidden, it is not able to be moused over anymore. What is the correct way to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution: your toggling span put it in another span that's transparent and half the size of the image and attach the event on it.

Another one: leave the hover bind to the image but check if the mouse is in the bottom half of the image.

I would recommend the first one.

Comment: The first solution is pretty smart, but it seems like a bit of a band-aid solution. I'm wondering if theres a way to do it without some sort of a css hack

Comment: I think that's the best way to do it. It just involves one extra container but i think it's strait forward.